# Show link only if folder contains a document

Tags: web-part, xslt

I have created a custom web part that displays information from a list of applications. I have created a sepearte document library that contains a folder for each application.  I created a 'View Documentation' link that will link to the correct folder for the application. However I would like this link only to display when the folder contains a document. Although my link works, the count function does not. Please help

```
<xsl:when test="  count(../{@DocumentLibrary}/{@Application}/) != 0">
   <td>
<b>View <a href="../{@DocumentLibrary}/{@Application}/">Documentation</a></b>
   </td>
</xsl:when>
```

Comment: The xsl count function counts the number of xml nodes in the given path. See reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256103.aspx. If you can't include the documents themselves in the xml then you have have to check this with code.

Comment: Ryan, Thank you for your response.  I have discovered that the count function only works with nodes. I don't think that it is plausible to include the documents themselves. Would you have an idea of how to check this with code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code example to check if a folder contains any documents:

```
using (SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web)
{
    SPList oList = web.Lists["ListName"];
    SPListItemCollection collListItems = null;
    foreach (SPFolder subFolder in oList.RootFolder.SubFolders)
    {
        if (subFolder.Name.ToLower() == FolderName.ToLower().Trim())
        {
            SPQuery oQuery = new SPQuery();
            oQuery.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name=’Modified’ Ascending=’False’ /></OrderBy>";
            oQuery.Folder = subFolder;
            collListItems = oList.GetItems(oQuery);
            int hasDocs = colListItems.Count() > 0;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```